# "$digest already in progress" when manually changing URL

Tags: angularjs, router, zone

### ["$digest already in progress"](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#diagnosing-this-error) when manually changing URL

I have a hybrid AngularJs/Angular app. If I'm on a page, say localhost/**home**, and I manually edit the URL to localhost/**otherPage** and hit enter, the browser navigates to the other page, but I get this error:

[image]

The error does *not* occur if:

- I navigate to the same page using in-app links
- I open a new tab to navigate directly to localhost/otherPage

The stacktrace doesn't show any of my code, so I'm not sure how to debug this. Also, I don't know what difference it makes to the router whether you're "editing" the URL to navigate from home to otherPage as opposed to directly resolving the otherPage URL in a new tab.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ## Diagnosing This Error
>
> When you get this error it can be rather daunting to diagnose the cause of the issue. The best course of action is to investigate the stack trace from the error. You need to look for places where `$apply` or `$digest` have been called and find the context in which this occurred.
>
> There should be two calls:
>
> - The first call is the good `$apply`/`$digest` and would normally be triggered by some event near the top of the call stack.
> - The second call is the bad `$apply`/`$digest` and this is the one to investigate.
>
> Once you have identified this call you work your way up the stack to see what the problem is.
>
> - If the second call was made in your application code then you should look at why this code has been called from within an `$apply`/`$digest`. It may be a simple oversight or maybe it fits with the sync/async scenario described earlier.
> - If the second call was made inside an AngularJS directive then it is likely that it matches the second programmatic event trigger scenario described earlier. In this case you may need to look further up the tree to what triggered the event in the first place.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope:inprog - Diagnosing This Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#diagnosing-this-error)

Comment: Thanks but there's only one call to $digest in the stacktrace,